# cards are shrinking when trying to add extra cards to the grid layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview, android-scrollview, android-gridlayout

In the android studio, when I try to add more cards and change the layout to scrollview, the window instead of scrolling shrinks the cards to fit the entire grid in the same window, whereas I want it to scroll and show both the image view and text view clearly in all the cards(text view below image view)

I know i am missing something very fundamental, but not able to get through.Please help.
this is my XML code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/jhyti"
        android:weightSum="10"

    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="294dp"
            android:layout_height="89dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:padding="14dp">

        <!--ROW 1 - -!>

        <!- -CARD 1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/stock1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CHAPTER 1"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--CARD 2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"

            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/stock2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CHAPTER 2"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <!--ROW 2 - -!>

         <!- -CARD 1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"

            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/stock3" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CHAPTER 3"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--CARD 2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"

            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/stock4" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CHAPTER 4"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <!--ROW 3 - -!>

        <!- -CARD 1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"

            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/stock5" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CHAPTER 5"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--CARD 2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"

            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/stock6" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CHAPTER 6"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



        <!--ROW 7 - -!>

         <!- -CARD 1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"

            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/stock1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CHAPTER 7"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--CARD 2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"

            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/stock2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CHAPTER 2"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>




    </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `weight` from your `Relative` and `GridLayout`.

Set height to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/jhyti"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="294dp"
                android:layout_height="89dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:padding="14dp">

            <!--ROW 1 - -!>

            <!- -CARD 1-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/stock1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="CHAPTER 1"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--CARD 2-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"

                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/stock2" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="CHAPTER 2"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <!--ROW 2 - -!>

             <!- -CARD 1-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"

                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/stock3" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="CHAPTER 3"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--CARD 2-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"

                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/stock4" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="CHAPTER 4"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <!--ROW 3 - -!>

            <!- -CARD 1-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"

                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/stock5" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="CHAPTER 5"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--CARD 2-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"

                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/stock6" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="CHAPTER 6"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <!--ROW 7 - -!>

             <!- -CARD 1-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"

                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/stock1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="CHAPTER 7"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--CARD 2-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"

                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/stock2" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="CHAPTER 2"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: solved my problem PARTIALLY, the scrolling part seems to work fine and the cards aren't shrinking but the text message under each image is still hidden and it's pretty important for my UI to have it.

Comment: try to adjust the height of your each imageview and Cardview to have a desired effect